# php - Can not insert multiple text inputs into database

Tags: php, mysql

This is my html code.

```
<form class="form-submit" method="post" action="sign-up-form.php" >
                    <div  id="change-color0">
                        <label><span class="turn-white0">01</span>Họ tên đầy đủ của bạn</label>
                        <input type="text" id="input" name="content[]" class="addtodo0">
                    </div>
                    <div id="change-color1">
                        <label><span class="turn-white1">02</span>Số chứng minh thư nhân dân của bạn</label>
                        <input type="text" id="input" name="content[]" class="addtodo1">                   
                    </div>
                    <div id="change-color2">
                        <label><span class="turn-white2">03</span>Địa chỉ thường trú của bạn</label>
                        <input type="text" id="input" name="content[]" class="addtodo2">
                    </div>
                    <div id="change-color3">
                        <label><span class="turn-white3">04</span>Tại sao bạn muốn trở thành học viên của dự án</label>
                        <input type="text" id="input" name="content[]" class="addtodo3">
                    </div>
                    <div id="change-color4">
                        <label><span class="turn-white4">05</span>Bạn nghĩ mình là ai</label>
                        <input type="text" id="input" name="content[]" class="addtodo4">
                    </div>
                    <div id="change-color5">
                        <label><span class="turn-white5">06</span>Trong mắt người khác bạn là ai</label>
                        <input type="text" id="input" name="content[]" class="addtodo5">
                    </div>
                    <div id="change-color6">
                        <label><span class="turn-white6">07</span>Bạn sợ nhất điều gì</label>
                        <input type="text" id="input" name="content[]" class="addtodo6">
                    </div>
                    <div id="change-color7">

                    <div class="row" id="log-out">
                <div id="submit-button">
                    <button class="btn btn-sharp">
                        <a name="submit" value="submit" id="submit-form">Gửi đơn</a>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div id="log-out-button">
                    <a href="homepage.html" id="log-out">ĐĂNG XUẤT</a>
                </div>
            </div>

                </form>
```

And this is my php code to insert the text fields into my database

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST["submit"])){

    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root","");
    mysql_select_db("db");

    foreach ($_POST['content'] as $content) {
        $data = mysql_real_escape_string($content);
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO form ( content ) VALUES ('".$data."')") or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
header("location: thank-you.html");
 ?>
```

Text editor doesnt show any error but the database shows nothing. I've tried

> implode()

UPDATE (php code)
I updated my code using PDO like this.

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST["submit"])){

    $pdo = new PDO("mysql: host = localhost; dbname = db","root","");

    die(var_dump($_POST['content']));

    foreach ($_POST['content'] as $content) {
        $query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO form(content) VALUES (:content)");
        $query->bindParam(":content", $content);
        $query->execute();
    }
}

 ?>
```

And thing does not show up still.

Comment: ignoring the use of a depreciated and removed library (use `mysqli_*`) and possible SQL Injection vulnerability (should really be using prepared statements) have you tried echoing your query to the screen and checking/running the generated queries manually to make sure that they are correct?

Comment: Check what is actually being sent to your php page with a browser (inspector view) and dump "content" in the php page to check where is the problem, anyway I suggest to use prepared statement so you pass data to sql as it is.

Comment: it shows nothing bro!

Comment: You miss the last </div>.. anyway you should set your buttontype to submit. otherwise <button class="btn btn-sharp" type="submit">

Comment: i fixed them all. but still doesnt work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should try this. I read this on stackover and it works.

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
    foreach ($_POST['content'] as $content) {
        $data1 = mysql_real_escape_string($content);
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO form (content) VALUES ('$data1')") or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```